# How to run specific automation tests in different chrome languages

Tags: java, spring, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, cucumber

I'm using spring, selenium and cucumber and I want to launch chrome in different languages for specific tests.
The issue that I have is that with spring my chromeDriver is a **@Bean**, so the spring context is initialized before the tests are and before any **@Before** tag that cucumber has.

This is my bean for chromeDriver:

```
@Bean(destroyMethod = "quit")
@Scope("cucumber-glue")
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "browser", havingValue = "chrome")
@Primary
public WebDriver chromeDriver() {
    Map<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();

    chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadsPath);
    chromePrefs.put("autofill.profile_enabled", false);

    chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
    chromeOptions.addArguments("start-maximized");

    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    return new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
}
```

And I would like to pass the values like this in the feature files:

```
@Chrome_es_CA
Scenario: Test 1 in es_CA

@Chrome_en_US
Scenario: Test 2 in en-US
```

If the way that I want to do it is not possible, what are the alternatives?

I know that I could pass the language through applications.properties but that wouldn't be the ideal scenario, since I'd like to have all tests ran in the same execution on jenkins.

Thanks in advance.